# Dictionary example for uimaFIT code based

Tags: java, uima

I'm having a look at [uimaFIT](https://uima.apache.org/uimafit.html) and I just had quite some difficulties to add a [Dictionary Annotator](https://uima.apache.org/d/uima-addons-current/DictionaryAnnotator/DictionaryAnnotatorUserGuide.html) to a [analyse engine](https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#d5e122).

This is my best shut so far:

```
public class LocationAnnotator extends JCasAnnotator_ImplBase {

    public static final String RES_DICTIONARY = "dictionary";

    @ExternalResource(key = RES_DICTIONARY)
    private DataResource resource;
    private Dictionary dictionary;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UimaContext context) throws ResourceInitializationException {
        super.initialize(context);
        try {
            DictionaryBuilder dictBuilder = new HashMapDictionaryBuilder();
            // create dictionary file parser
            DictionaryFileParserImpl fileParser = new DictionaryFileParserImpl();
            fileParser.parseDictionaryFile(resource.getUri().getPath(), resource.getInputStream(), dictBuilder);
            dictionary = dictBuilder.getDictionary();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ResourceInitializationException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void process(JCas cas) throws AnalysisEngineProcessException {
        String docText = cas.getDocumentText();
        for (String line : docText.split("\n")) {
            for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
                if (dictionary.contains(word)) {
                    int pos = docText.indexOf(word);
                    Location annotation = new Location(cas, pos, pos + word.length());
                    annotation.addToIndexes();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I'm executing the engine like this:

```
CollectionReaderDescription reader = CollectionReaderFactory.createReaderDescription(CvReader.class, CvReader.PARAM_INPUT_FILE, "docs/simple-doc.txt");

AnalysisEngineDescription tokenizer = AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(LocationAnnotator.class);
ExternalResourceFactory.bindResource(tokenizer, LocationAnnotator.RES_DICTIONARY, "META-INF/dictionaries/location.dict.xml");

for (JCas cas : SimplePipeline.iteratePipeline(reader, tokenizer)) {
    for (Location location : JCasUtil.select(cas, Location.class)) {
        System.out.println("Found location: " + location.getCoveredText());
    }
}
```

Is there no more elegant way? Don't like the initialization. Would expect to init the dictionary with an annotation as the `@ExternalResource`.

I would be glade if someone could provide me with a more simple example.. Thanks!

Comment: uimaFIT annotations like @ExternalResource only work if you a) inherit from the uimaFIT-version of JCasAnnotator_ImplBase and b) if you call super.initialize(...) when you override the initialize(...) method in your derived class.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted b) in the code above. Looks nicer but a direct instantiation is not possible, I guess?

Comment: What do you mean by "direct instantiation"?

Comment: I would expect something like the `@ExternalResource` annotation also for directories to exist, so that I don't need to initialize it myself in the `initialize(UimaContext context)` method.

Comment: It is a matter of how the external resource is implemented. It is possible to implement a smarter external resource, e.g. implement a dictionary that is an external resource, and implement the loading logic inside that. This makes the code for the external resource a little more complex but your component code becomes more compact.